# Display images on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, reactjs

I'm building an app to display images on my React page. The images have been uploaded onto a local folder. I coupled my React app with a NodeJS server and MongoDB.

I want to display all the img that are saved in the folder. 
I've been trying to use the path of the file but I don't think it works with the img tag.

Could anyone help clarify on that?

```js
class showAllPhotos extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      library: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/all')
    .then((response) => {
      let arr = response.data;
      console.log('arr', arr);
      this.setState({
        library: arr
      });
      console.log("response data", arr);
      console.log('library it worked', response.status); // ex: 200
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      console.log('error getting library', error.status);
    });

  }

  render() {

      let renderLibrary = () => {
        return(
          <div>
            {this.state.library.map(function(library) {
              return(
                <div className="row" >
                  <div className="col-xs-6 col-md-6" id='card'>
                    <img src={library.path} alt='some text'/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        )
      }

    return (
      <div className="Container">
        <div>
        {renderLibrary()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default showAllPhotos;
```

and here's my route for the backend - checked on Postmate and it's ok.

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Photo = require('../model/photo');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  Photo.find({}, function(err, photos){
    if(err){
      res.json({error:err});
    }
    res.json(photos);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to require the image to use it in `img` tag. Use it like this -

```
<img src={require(library.path)} />
```

Comment: Oh thanks! but I get an error " cannot find module '.' webpack missing module "

Comment: When using images- 

1. For **URLs** -  use `<img src='IMG_URL' />`

2. For **Local Images** - use `<img src={require('IMG_PATH')} />`  to import local files in your javascript.

Can you give me some more information regarding the error. Like when did it occur - during `npm start`? ....or anything.

Comment: I see! Error on my terminal during `npm start` 78:50-71 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Comment: Oh!! That's strange. So it doesn't seem to me like the issue with `img` tag now. But still this is what I'd do - **1.** Try removing the `img` tag to see if the error remains. **1.1.** If the error goes, then check if the path is coming right and if the require() is working properly or not. **1.2.** And if the error doesn't go away. Then that's another story (not related to this `img`).

Comment: yeah, I took the `img` tag and the error went away. I think it's the path I'm using that is wrong! when I `console.log(library.path)` I get an error.

Comment: Oh... okay. All the best